# Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 0015g00000SAP87AAH; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, duplicate account not allowed: []

Tags: apex, trigger, after-trigger, updaterecord

Create field called “Count of Contacts” on Account Object. When we add the Contacts for that Account then count will populate in the field on Account details page. When we delete the Contacts for that Account, then Count will update automatically.

My trigger:

```java
trigger countContacts on Contact (after insert,after delete)
{
    list<account> addaccount=new list<account>();
    list<Id> addcon=new list<id>();
    if(trigger.isInsert){
        for(contact con:trigger.new)
        {
           addcon.add(con.accountid);
        }
    }
    
    if(trigger.isDelete)
    {
        for(contact con:trigger.old)
        {
            addcon.add(con.accountid);
        }
    }

    list<account> acc = [select id, No_of_Contacts__c, (select id from contacts) from account where id in :addcon];
      
    for(account a:acc)
    {
        a.No_of_Contacts__c = a.contacts.size();
        addaccount.add(a);
    }
         
    try
    {
        update addaccount;
    }
    catch(DMLException e)
    {
        system.debug(e);
    }
}
```

This code is giving exception whenever I add contacts and accounts and the value is also not updated.

Can anyone explain me what is the issue? and how to solve it?

Comment: As per given error, Please check with account validation rule settings and resolve the account validation error and try again.

Comment: Hello Nehal, could you please share what you have attempted so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code it doesn't seem like any duplication is occurring. The issue is probably on a custom Validation Rule on the Account object which is somehow preventing an Account from being updated correctly.

I'd suggest you check first the conditions for the `duplicate account not allowed` rule to fire and assure that the Account related to the Contact you're trying to add is not falling into it.

Best regards!